# How do i remove outline around input field?

Tags: css

I'm creating a contact form and when I click into my input field there is an outline around it.

[image]

---

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="row contact-form">
                <div class="col-sm-8">

<div class="row contact-form">
    <div class="col-sm-8">

        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="firstName">First name<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="fname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="lastName">Last name<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lname">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried this css, but didn't work:

```
.contact-form input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

How can I remove it?
Thanks

Comment: Why not simply
 .contact-form input {
    outline: none;
} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use this line

```
.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. For Chrome we also have to use -webkit-box-shadow

Comment: Avoid using `!important`, instead mention the actual element itself to gain more specificity. Ex: `input.form-control:focus` OR `.form-control[type="text"]:focus`

Answer (score 3):

1) `outline: none;` is what You are looking for

2) Using `!important` is a bad practice. Try not to do that

3) Never hide the outline!

Take a look

https://medium.com/better-programming/a11y-never-remove-the-outlines-ee4efc7a9968

Comment: Definitely should be marked as better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
textarea:hover, 
input:hover, 
textarea:active, 
input:active, 
textarea:focus, 
input:focus,
{
    outline:0px !important;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```